# Beginner - changing number based list with input that is not a str

Tags: python, exception, input, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make an easy tic tac toe game in python, but I am currently stuck at changing the list that is used to change the grid                 to my problem:

```py
grid = [" ", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]                       
def grids():                                                                   
    print(grid[1] + " | " + grid[2] + " | " + grid[3])                        
    print(grid[4] + " | " + grid[5] + " | " + grid[6])                                 
    print(grid[7] + " | " + grid[8] + " | " + grid[9])                             

.....                                                                                 
# picked is what ive selected ( X or O )                                                                                              

while True:                                                                      
    grids()                                                                           
    choose = input(f"choose a number and place your {picked}:")               
    if isinstance(choose, int) not in grid and choose not in grid:              
        print("wrong input, try again")                                            
    else:                                                                              
        grid[choose] = grid[choose].replace(grid[choose], picked)
```

(not 100% sure if the last part is correct, I changed so much the last hour that I don't know if it is even working)

I made it work before, the grid list got changed the way I liked it to.
but only if I changed the `input =` ..to `int(input)=`..

But as soon as I typed a string as an input (like "d") it crashed and don't know what to do against it. I tried the `try/except` function as well without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the way to find input type then you can use `String.isnumeric`.

```py
def until_user_enters_a_number():
  clear = False
  entered = 0
  while not clear:
    entered = input('I\'m going no where before you enter a number: ');
    clear = entered.isnumeric()
    # make sure the number is between 0 and 9
    # may be you also want to make sure the number wasn't selected once already
  return int(entered)
```

This will keep the user in a loop until he enters a valid input, you can add more assertions in it as well.